# How to get the values of dynamically added rows into database?

Tags: php, javascript, html, row, addition

I have a table form which contains a part where the rows can be added dynamically by clicking on add button. As usual, why I am coming here is having trouble in adding those values in the added rows into database. I mean, the values on the dynamically added rows are not being saved into the database, only the values of the first row is being added.

This is the script:

EDIT:

```
<script language="Javascript">
var i=1;
function addRowToTable()
{


 i++;
  m.r.value = i;
  var tbl = document.getElementById('table');
  var lastRow = tbl.rows.length;
  var iteration = lastRow;
  var row = tbl.insertRow(lastRow);

  var cellLeft = row.insertCell(0);
  var textNode = document.createTextNode(iteration);
  cellLeft.appendChild(textNode);

  var cellRightSel1 = row.insertCell(1);
  var sel = document.createElement('select');
  sel.name = 'name' + iteration;
  sel.setAttribute("onchange", "choosec(this);");    
  var item = new Option("","");
  sel.options[sel.length] = item;
    <?
    while($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)){                                    
    ?>
  var item = new Option("<?=$data["Name"];?>","<?=$data["ID"];?>");
  sel.options[sel.length] = item;
  <? } ?>
  cellRightSel1.appendChild(sel);

  var cellRightSel2 = row.insertCell(2);
  var sel = document.createElement('select');
  sel.name = 'class' + iteration;
  sel.setAttribute("onchange", "choosepoint(this);");    
  var item = new Option ("","");
  sel.options[sel.length] = item;
    <?
    while($data = mysql_fetch_array($result_sub)){                                    
    ?>
  var item = new Option("<?=$data["Class"];?>","<?=$data["ID"];?>");
  sel.options[sel.length] = item;
  <? } ?>
  cellRightSel2.appendChild(sel);

  var cellRight = row.insertCell(3);
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.id = 'point' + iteration;
  cellRight.appendChild(div);
}
    </script>

<form id="m" name="m" method="POST" action="submit.php">
<input type="hidden" name="menu_id" value="<?=$menu_id;?>">
<input type="hidden" name="r" id="r">
<table align="center" class="table">
    <tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="tablesubtitle">Adjustment</td>
        <td class="tablesubtitle"><input type="text" name="adjustment" size="2"></td>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="tablesubtitle">Component</td>
        <td class="tablesubtitle">
        <table id="table">
    <tr>
        <td>No</td>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Class</td>
        <td>Point</td>
        <td>Action</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
            <td>1</td>
        <td><select name="name">
            <option value="#">&nbsp;</option>
            <?php
                    opendb();
                $query = "SELECT * FROM student";
                $result = mysql_query($query);
                while($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                    $ID = $data['ID'];
                    $Name = $data['Name'];
                    echo "<option value='$ID'>$Name</option>";
                }
            ?>
             </select>
        </td>
        <td><select name='class' onchange="choosepoint(this);">
            <option value="#">&nbsp;</option>
            <?php
                    opendb();
                $query = "SELECT * FROM student2";
                $result = mysql_query($query);
                while($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                        $ID1 = $data['ID'];
                    $class = $data['Class'];
                    echo "<option value='$ID'>$class</option>";
                }
            ?>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
                <div id="point" name="point"></div>
            </td>
            <td><input type="button" value=" + " onClick="addRowToTable();"> | <input type="button" value=" - " onClick="removeRowFromTable();"></td>
    </tr>
</table>    
        </td>
        <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td align="center"><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td>
        </tr>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Submit.php

```
<?php
include ("c/config.php");
include ("c/db.php");

opendb();
$query1 = "select * from student where ID='$name'";
$result1 = querydb($query1);
$data = mysql_fetch_array($result1);
    $adjustment = $data['adjustment'];

$num = $_POST['r'];
//echo $num;
for($i=0; $i<=$num; $i++){
if(isset($_REQUEST['name$i'])){
    $name = $_REQUEST['name$i'];
}
if(isset($_REQUEST['class$i'])){
    $class = $_REQUEST['class$i'];
}
if(isset($_REQUEST['point$i'])){
    $point = $_REQUEST['point$i'];
}

$query2 = "INSERT INTO student3
            VALUES('$adjustment','$name','$class','$point')";
$result2 = querydb($query2);
}
closedb();
?>
```

Comment: There is no insert or update statement in your code. Also there's way too much code here. Reduce the amount of code and only post the part that gives you trouble.

Comment: Uh, I forgot that, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out the problems.
This is my latest code:

```
var i=0;
function addRowToTable()
{
 i++;
  m.r.value = i;
  var tbl = document.getElementById('table');
  var lastRow = tbl.rows.length;
  var iteration = lastRow - 1;
  var row = tbl.insertRow(lastRow);

  var cellLeft = row.insertCell(0);
  var textNode = document.createTextNode(iteration);
  cellLeft.appendChild(textNode);

  var cellRightSel1 = row.insertCell(1);
  var sel = document.createElement('select');
  sel.name = 'name' + iteration;
  sel.setAttribute("onchange", "choosec(this);");    
  var item = new Option("","");
  sel.options[sel.length] = item;
    <?
    while($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)){                                    
    ?>
  var item = new Option("<?=$data["Name"];?>","<?=$data["ID"];?>");
  sel.options[sel.length] = item;
  <? } ?>
  cellRightSel1.appendChild(sel);

  var cellRightSel2 = row.insertCell(2);
  var sel = document.createElement('select');
  sel.name = 'class' + iteration;
  sel.setAttribute("onchange", "choosepoint(this);");    
  var item = new Option ("","");
  sel.options[sel.length] = item;
    <?
    while($data = mysql_fetch_array($result_sub)){                                    
    ?>
  var item = new Option("<?=$data["Class"];?>","<?=$data["ID"];?>");
  sel.options[sel.length] = item;
  <? } ?>
  cellRightSel2.appendChild(sel);

  var cellRight = row.insertCell(3);
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.id = 'point' + iteration;
  cellRight.appendChild(div);
}
    </script>

<form id="m" name="m" method="POST" action="submit.php">
<input type="hidden" name="menu_id" value="<?=$menu_id;?>">
<input type="hidden" name="r" id="r">
<table align="center" class="table">
    <tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="tablesubtitle">Adjustment</td>
        <td class="tablesubtitle"><input type="text" name="adjustment" size="2"></td>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="tablesubtitle">Component</td>
        <td class="tablesubtitle">
        <table id="table">
    <tr>
        <td>No</td>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Class</td>
        <td>Point</td>
        <td>Action</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
            <td>1</td>
        <td><select name="name">
            <option value="#">&nbsp;</option>
            <?php
                    opendb();
                $query = "SELECT * FROM student";
                $result = mysql_query($query);
                while($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                    $ID = $data['ID'];
                    $Name = $data['Name'];
                    echo "<option value='$ID'>$Name</option>";
                }
            ?>
             </select>
        </td>
        <td><select name='class' onchange="choosepoint(this);">
            <option value="#">&nbsp;</option>
            <?php
                    opendb();
                $query = "SELECT * FROM student2";
                $result = mysql_query($query);
                while($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                        $ID1 = $data['ID'];
                    $class = $data['Class'];
                    echo "<option value='$ID'>$class</option>";
                }
            ?>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
                <div id="point" name="point"></div>
            </td>
            <td><input type="button" value=" + " onClick="addRowToTable();"> | <input type="button" value=" - " onClick="removeRowFromTable();"></td>
    </tr>
</table>    
        </td>
        <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td align="center"><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td>
        </tr>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>

<?php
include ("c/config.php");
include ("c/db.php");

opendb();
$query1 = "select * from student where ID='$name'";
$result1 = querydb($query1);
$data = mysql_fetch_array($result1);
    $adjustment = $data['adjustment'];

$num = $_POST['r'];
//echo $num;
for($i=0;$i<=$num;$i++){
if(isset($_REQUEST['name$i'])){$name = $_REQUEST['name$i'];}
if(isset($_REQUEST['class$i'])){$class = $_REQUEST['class$i'];}
if(isset($_REQUEST['point$i'])){$point = $_REQUEST['point$i'];}

$query2 = "INSERT INTO student3
            VALUES('$adjustment','$name','$class','$point')";
$result2 = querydb($query2);
}
closedb();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use jquery and give each form element in the row a unique id then call

```
addRowToTable('234') //or whatever the id is
```

then in addRowToTable(id) function

```
$('form_element'+id).val();
```

Send this to a jquery $.post

Comment: Thanks Michael for the suggestion, but I do not understand about Jquery though it seems easier, I will learn it.
Anyway, I've found the answer.
Thank you.